# Java program using methods from one class on another class

Tags: java

I'm writing a code in which a user has to be able to register an ocurrence. I have a class named Citizen and another named Ocurrence:

```
public ArrayList addOcurrencia(String oc){
        listaOcurrencias.add(oc);
        return listaOcurrencias;
    }
```

I would use this function if I wanted to do a

```
Ocurrence.addOcurrencia("Ocurrence")
```

but I want the user to be able to make the ocurrence from the user class. Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want to accomplish firstly require a static method.

```
public static ArrayList addOcurrencia(String oc){
   listaOcurrencias.add(oc);
   return listaOcurrencias;
}
```

Secondly, you need a static `ArrayList` object, and if your program require multi-threading, well, some sort of syncronization or access control.

I'm missing something on your last sentence, could you re-elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of your Occurance class where you want to call it.

```
Occurance occ = new Occurance();
```

And then use the object to call the method.

```
list = occ.addOcurrencia(oc);
```